# VBA Code for Saving a workbook on to a networked drive

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint-2010, save

Hi i am using this VBA code to save a Excel Workbook:

```
Sub Button10_Click()
    Dim SaveName As String
       SaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("N2").Text
       ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="z:\" & _
           SaveName & ".xlsm"
End Sub
```

This code works once i open the template and commit the first save but when i make changes to that workbook and try to save it wont allow me to overwrite and gives me a 1004 Error.

But when i open the template again and put the same FileName it lets me overwrite by giving me a prompt box.

Is there a way i can get it to overwrite?

Oh and cel N2 is the concatenate of B2 and B3 which is the site name and the date with a "-" in between if this is causing the problem.

Thanks in advance for your help

What i have done to resolve the problem for myself:

Adapted the workbook to remove any spaces in the fileName

SaveName is nowWeeklyTakingsv9 but gets changed from siteName(B2)-WeekendingDate(B3) Site name takes white spaces out putting "_"

I tried trimming But client whats the fileName to be a specific SiteName to the date of the week end.

Attempted to create a work around so the dialog box would open giving the fileName and the Networked drive location but this would not work on clients machines

Further details of what its doing

I have 26 Client sites (Library's)

each site has its own networked drive connected to SharePoint

What i have done is set up each networked drive connected to there sharepoint library

i Set the drive letter to Z as to not Interfere with they're own network set up

So that i dont have to create 26 workbooks i have got to this point where it will save once but they need to go into the workbook every day and make changes.

So when the workbook is opened B2-B3 arent changed so the fileName is the same but it does not let me overwrite what is there

SharePoint is NOT the problem here its the overwrite problem i am having on Excel

Comment: this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: this has nothing to do with programming **NOR VBA**.

Comment: then revise your question and provide more details. make it a good question and you'll get a good answer. Here, on Stack Overflow, we do not answer poor questions as they are most of the time deleted.. If my answer is going to get deleted what's the point of *sharing* knowledge...simple waste of time

Comment: Because you're new to this site therefore [*`unfamiliar with how it works`*.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) See [*`what is on topic here`*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Attempts at solving. Have you stepped through code? What is the `SaveName` at run-time when it's used? Have you checked for white-spaces? Have you tried using `Trim(SaveName)`? there just too many things you haven't done before actually asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use network saving all the time within the organisation i work for.

Only use SaveAs when saving as a new file.

When you want a workbook to save itself over itself i have found the following code successful:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
```

Note that this code is executed every 30 seconds or so each time the user clicks (file is used 24 hours a day!), and it hasnt failed since it was implemented (oct 2013).

Good Luck.

Comment: Perfect worked and very easy to implement much appreciated.